# Python 3.6 (PyCharm) Connection through Proxy Error

Tags: python, proxy, pycharm, plotly

**I am having errors connecting to the internet when pulling data or connecting to a host**. My current project involves creating a choropleth and network graph using plot.ly (plotly) in Python 3.6. I have successfully created the network graph following their documentation for offline usage.

Since there is no choropleth offline method, **I use the following to read data**:

```
    import urllib 
    urllib.request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2011_us_ag_exports.csv')
```

I then encounter the following error message:

```
    urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection 
    attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after 
    a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host 
    has failed to respond>
```

I am operating on a remote server through a proxy. I have created environment variables for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. Furthermore, I get the correct proxies if I type:

```
   urllib.request.getproxies()
```

Regarding **connecting to the host for an online network graph**, if I type:

```
   import urllib3
   import certifi
   from urllib3 import ProxyManager, make_headers
   default_headers = urllib3.make_headers(proxy_basic_auth = 
   'username:password')
   http = urllib3.ProxyManager('http://proxy:port/',
                        headers = default_headers)
   r = http.request('GET', 'http://plot.ly')
   import plotly.plotly as py
   import plotly.graph_objs as go
   import plotly
   plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='plotlyuser', 
   api_key='plotlyapikey')
   plotly.tools.set_config_file(world_readable = False, sharing = 'private')

   trace0 = go.Scatter(
   x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
   y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
   )
   trace1 = go.Scatter(
   x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
   y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
   )
   data = [trace0, trace1]
   py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line', auto_open=True)
```

I get the following error codes (every code runs fine except for the last line above):

```
  TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
  connected party 
  did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection 
  failed because connected host has failed to respond

  urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: 
  <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000000292C437780>: 
  Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt 
  failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period 
  of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed 
  to respond

  urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='plot.ly', 
  port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /clientresp (Caused by 
  NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
  0x000000292C437780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] 
  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
  respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
  connected host has failed to respond'))

  requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='plot.ly', 
  port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /clientresp (Caused by 
  NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 
  0x000000292C437780>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] 
  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
  respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
  connected host has failed to respond'))

  plotly.exceptions.PlotlyRequestError: No message
```

Sorry for the long question, but I have been struggling with this issue for a while!